# I don't understand how to UV map my model while keep all parts separated

Tags: uv

I'm trying to texture a character. I've been using smart UV project, but it always ends up having artifacts and looking messed up.

I followed tutorials to mark seams and unwrap, but instead of getting the various pieces I "separated" via seams, I'm getting two or three separates and a whole big ugly mess with the rest of the body.

I need to keep all parts separated so I can paint on the face and not have any other random body part get painted as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are having some black artefacts on your mesh. They could be a result of non confirming face normals and could possibly be the reason why the uv unwrap works badly. Try Make Normals Consistent (CTRL-N in edit mode). Then try uv unwrap again.

If that doesn't help, upload the file so we could have a look.

Comment: you have to manually make seam lines to the UV, and then unwrap from there. It would be a great starting point and easier to map mesh's problems. About black artifacts, you might have issues with non manifold vertexes, or similar. You might need to do retopology on your model to both simplify it and correct it.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5847" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5847/)

I tried making normals consistent and still doesnt work. so heres the file.
I tried also making a retopology, it wasted around 4 hours, and i realized that the model i was retopologing had around 20k faces, while the original only had 5k, so i kinda gave up there because i really fucked up. 
Is there any to fix it other than retopology? :(

Answer (score 0):

The seams you have created aren't enough. You need to add additional seams to make it unwrap properly, especially on the hand, the lower body (some edges aren't set to seams). Also, there's some unmerged verts in-between the breasts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that a bunch of vertices are pinned (red dots in the uv view) and thus cant be moved into the bounds of the texture. Just select everything in the uv editor and unpin them using right click -> unpin.
The other seams look good, but there are 4 edges missing - one near the foot, at the lower body and on the eyebrowns.

If you add seams there you can use the regular unwrap to give each surface its own paintable uv space. (apply the mirror modifier beforehand unless you want symetric textures)

[image]